# C++ support for non-ASCII data files

Tags: c++, c, file-io, format

I can't find any reference to how to write and read non-ASCII files in C++.

I would like to create my file format while expressing a precise pattern and markup of the informations inside the file, but basically with `fstream` I can only create text files. text mode or binary mode doesn't really matter for this purpose, the result is always an ASCII file.

How to write a file byte by byte like the ones that you can't simply parse with a text editor and they have their own definition ?

Comment: If you write plain text to a file, it doesn't matter if it's opened in binary or text mode, the text will be there anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, but my point is that i don't want text, i want a data file and i would like to create my own stream/pattern inside that file, if i write "12" to the file I don't want to read "12" from the file, I would like to able to read the file ( externally ) only with an hexeditor like any other data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native support for this, use serialization if you want to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is to treat the file as a byte stream, this can be achieved by using read() and write(). The normal stream operator `<< >>` cannot be used when dealing directly with the file when its not text.

Normally you would create your own read/write functions on top of the read()/write() to overload the stream operators

Another approach is to use fread() fwrite() where you create a struct with the layout of a record then use that in fread()/fwrite()

```
typedef struct
{
   short id;
   char name[64];
} rec;

rec A;

fread( &A, sizeof(A), 1, fp );
```

Comment: beware that that this struct may well have a size of 8, even as you think it would be 6 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a file you can't "read with an editor", it just means that the data is not stored in text form. As others have said, C and C++ doesn't make much difference between text and binary forms of files - it's just a few simple rules about conversions (e.g. line endings) and conventions (e.g. end of file can be marked with a character, because file lengths are in blocks, but we don't want an exact multiple of 512 byte blocks in a text file, so CTRL-D or CTRL-Z is used to mark the end of thefile). In binary mode, "anything and everything goes".

In many respects, binary files are very much like text files in the respect that the compiler won't know WHAT your data represents. If a text file contains:

```
12345 Glurg 12.88
1Ab9Z Flarf 6.89
```

It would be your program that decides that the first column is the product ID (reading the first line, you'd think it's an integer, but since the second one can't be represented as an integer, it must be stored as a string), the second is the product name, and the third is a price, maybe? Or the weight? (in kilos, grams, pounds, tons?)

So, likewise for binary files, your program needs to know what each byte or collection of bytes mean.

If it's a well-known format (PDF, Excel spreadsheet, or something like that), there may be libraries available either free or for purchase, that handle that format. If not, you need a good description of the format of the file itself, and use the read/write or streambuf functionality described above.

If the format is of your own doing, or at least not uber-portable, you may be able to form structs that have the right format, and read those structs as one read operation, and write as one write operation. If the format is intended to be portable, that probably won't work - and beware that the method of reading and writing structs is not so portable, because compilers may put gaps in a struct, which varies depending on the architecture of the machine.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't support any binary format directly. The main reason is that there is no generally used binary format but many different ones. The stream buffers (i.e., the classes derived from `std::streambuf`) can be used to read bytes from an external destination or write byte to an external destination but you'd need to create a suitable set of binary formatted input and output functions.

Comment: can you point me to the right direction with a practical example ?

Comment: A *long* time ago I have created [binio](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/binio.tar.gz) as an example of binary streams could look like. I don't know if it still compiles but the basic ideas are still valid. You might want to use a different binary formatting, though.